# ProgressBar is not shown when visibility is set to VISIBLE

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a ProgressBar over a Google Maps view. The progress bar does show up if I set it as `VISIBLE` in the layout editor, but this is not what I want. Instead, I want it to be `INVISIBLE` and make it visible when there's stuff loading in the background. However, the progress bar stays hidden.

The layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Google Maps view -->
    <view
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <!-- The progress bar to show when stuff is loading in background -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progress="0"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code related to the problem is like this:

```
ProgressBar m_pbLoading;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    m_pbLoading = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);

    ...
}

// This gets called when stuff starts loading in the background
@Override
public void onStartLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartLoading()");
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}

// This gets called when stuff stops loading in the background
@Override
public void onStopLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStopLoading()");
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ...
}
```

So basically, the progress bar is initially set to `INVISIBLE`, and when loading starts, it should show up. When loading stops, it would be hidden again. However, this does not happen. The progress bar is only visible if I set it as visible in the layout.

Comment: make sure both this methods  onStartLoading() & onStopLoading() running on ui thread

Comment: @KaranMer They both are running on the UI thread.

Comment: try making it visible once from oncreate and tell whether its shown or not

Comment: @KaranMer It shows up this way.

Comment: then i guess your methods are not on ui thread or not even being called.

Comment: @KaranMer They are called (the log messages show up), and they are running on the UI thread - I've double-checked it, and I do other UI-related stuff there as well that works just fine. I did try to set the progress bar visibility on a handler runnable, and this made it work. This is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add setVisibility in a separate UI thread.

```
 public void run() {  
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        { 
          //Setvisibility method
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try so

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- The progress bar to show when stuff is loading in background -->
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:progress="0"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<!-- Google Maps view -->
<view
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
@Override
public void onStartLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartLoading()");
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}

// This gets called when stuff stops loading in the background
@Override
public void onStopLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStopLoading()");
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ...
}
```

**Add**

Or gone google maps view:

```
@Override
public void onStartLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartLoading()");
    GoogleMaps.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}

// This gets called when stuff stops loading in the background
@Override
public void onStopLoading()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onStopLoading()");
    m_pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    GoogleMaps.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}
```